# Embedded video player not showing and not playing a video file

Tags: php, html

I am developing a PHP backend to my mobile app.

There is a part where I need to show and play a hosted video file.

This is how am I trying it:

```
  $data[$i]['video'] = '<video controls width="500", height="300><source src="pacientes/'.$data[$i]['video'].'" type= "video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"></video>';
```

Here hou have the value for `$data[$i]['video']` that should be an example of the kind of video files I will find in he backend

```
32365bec-7ec8-4b16-a91c-58e12f68cdba1575964120438935622.mp4
```

And here yoy have the video file URL

https://capenergy-app.com/administrar/application/admin/pacientes/32365bec-7ec8-4b16-a91c-58e12f68cdba1575964120438935622.mp4

And here you a screenshot from the video player using the above code to show it.

[image]

The video is not played when clicking on the play button, and the video duration is set to 0:00.

What do I need to change to my code to show the video and let me play it?

Comment: `type= "video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"` looks to be missing a `"` somewhere, in fact after another look you seem to be missing a few `"` double check that code, for example `height="300>` random `,` after width attribute

Answer (score 1):

You must put the full video path at the source's src

```
<source src="full_path" > </source>
```

Answer (score 1):

Double check spelling, for example: some " are missing. And there is no need to add a `,` after attributes.

Fix:

```php
$data[$i]['video'] = '<video controls width="500" height="300"><source src="pacientes/'.$data[$i]['video'].'" type= "video/mp4"; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"></video>';
```